# Reset password on Galaxy Player

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, password, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-player

I have a Samsung Galaxy Player 4.0 and I haven't used it in ages. With that being said, I forgot my password. When I tried to unlock it, it told me to put in my email, but I forgot my password to that as well.

I want to know if there is a way to reset it, or just figure out the password to my email. Now my device doesn't let me try to put my password in because I tried too many times and failed. Is there a way that I can reset it?

Answer (score 0):

Olright mate you will have to wipe/ reset the whole device to do this Remove the battery. Replace the battery but do not power the device on. Hold down the Volume Down + Menu buttons then press the Power button. Hold the Power button for 2-4 seconds and release it without releasing the Volume Down or Menu button. Your phone will boot into hboot mode. Use Volume down to navigate the options and the Home Button to select Choose "Clear Storage" (sometimes named 'Wipe Data / Factory Reset') Confirm your choice and wait for the device to do the work.  Let me know if it works buddy.